# how to remove special character "," from a string using perl

Tags: perl

hi i have some data like below

```
     S_ METHOD m0 : 47|8@0- (1,0) [0|0] ""  
     S_ CTRL m1 : 15|8@0- (0.01,-200) [0|0] ""
```

from above 2 lines i am trying to extract that are in curve brackets () i have written a perl script

```
          my @temp_signal = split(":",$line);
          my @signal= split(" ",@temp_signal[0]);
          my @Factor_temp1 = split (" ",@temp_signal[1]);
          my @factor_temp = split ('\(',@Factor_temp1[1]);
          my @factor = chop(@factor_temp);
          my @offset = split (",",@factor_temp);
          print OUTFILE1 "@offset[0]\n";
          print OUTFILE1 "$signal[1]\n";
```

but when am trying to print @offset[1] & @offset[0] its printing some other value which is not even exist in the line how can i get the values as

```
               1  0
               0.01  -200
```

Comment: The problem is that you're passing an array to the fourth `split`. The operators evaluate their operands in scalar context. Arrays in scalar context evaluate to the number of elements they have.

Comment: You probably use `use strict;` (good!) but you aren't using `use warnings;` (bad!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression match to extract what's inside parentheses separated by a comma:

```
if ( my @numbers = $line =~ /\((.*),(.*)\)/) {
    print "$numbers[0] $numbers[1]\n";
}
```